# Clean way to revert back to ?page=1 (using flask-paginate) when a form is submitted

Tags: python, flask, pagination

I have a form in my template that when submitted, provides search filters for my database query.  The query otherwise returns all documents. I am using **flask-paginate** to navigate the results.  
 My bug is, if the user is on page 2 when they submit the form, the page reloads page 2 with the results of the new query, even if the number of documents returned does not equate to more than 1 page. In this case, the page that loads is just blank and there are no pagination links to navigate back to page 1. So far, I have semi solved this by changing the value of flask-paginate's 'page' variable to equal 1 when the form is submitted. It now seems to load the results from page 1, when I print(page) it correctly prints '1'. However, the query string in the url still says ?page=2. I am therefore looking for a cleaner solution? or a way to clear the query string?

```
    @app.route("/thingstodo/<city>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def suggestion_list(city):
    form = FilterResultsForm()
    cities = mongo.db.cities
    page, per_page, offset = get_page_args(
        page_parameter="page", per_page_parameter="per_page"
    )
    print(page) 
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        page = 1
    per_page = 3
    offset = (page - 1) * per_page
    query = ""
    if form.validate_on_submit() or "filters" in session:
        filters = (
            form.category.data if form.category.data else session["filters"]
        )
        session["filters"] = filters
        array = []
        for filter in filters:
            newdict = {}
            newdict["thingsToDo.category"] = filter
            array.append(newdict)
        query = cities.aggregate(
            [
                {"$unwind": "$thingsToDo"},
                {"$match": {"location": city, "$or": array}},
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "users",
                        "localField": "thingsToDo.author",
                        "foreignField": "username",
                        "as": "user_profile",
                    }
                },
                {"$unwind": "$user_profile"},
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "suggestion": "$thingsToDo.suggestion",
                        "cost": "$thingsToDo.cost",
                        "category": "$thingsToDo.category",
                        "url": "$thingsToDo.url",
                        "comment": "$thingsToDo.comment",
                        "author": "$user_profile.username",
                        "profile": "$user_profile.picture",
                    }
                },
            ]
        )
    else:
        query = cities.aggregate(
            [
                {"$match": {"location": city}},
                {"$unwind": "$thingsToDo"},
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "users",
                        "localField": "thingsToDo.author",
                        "foreignField": "username",
                        "as": "user_profile",
                    }
                },
                {"$unwind": "$user_profile"},
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "suggestion": "$thingsToDo.suggestion",
                        "cost": "$thingsToDo.cost",
                        "category": "$thingsToDo.category",
                        "url": "$thingsToDo.url",
                        "comment": "$thingsToDo.comment",
                        "author": "$user_profile.username",
                        "profile": "$user_profile.picture",
                    }
                },
            ]
        )
    results = list(query)
    total = len(results)
    suggestions = results[offset: offset + per_page]
    pagination = Pagination(
        page=page, per_page=per_page, total=total, css_framework="bootstrap4"
    )
    return render_template(
        "thingstodo.html",
        city=city,
        things=suggestions,
        page=page,
        per_page=per_page,
        pagination=pagination,
        form=form,
        title="Things to do",
    )
```